# Rcpp: How can I get the size of a Rcpp::Nullable NumericVector

Tags: rcpp

I want to translate a R function into Rcpp, a simple test code is as follow, but I do not know how to deal with  the arguments which is set NULL by default.

```
test<- function(t=NULL,tmax=NULL,tmin=NULL){
  if(is.null(t)){
    yout=(tmax-tmin)*(tmin+tmax)
  }else{
    yout=2*t
  }
  return(yout)
}

test(tmax=1:3,tmin=0:2)




  // [[Rcpp::export]]
    NumericVector cpptest(Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::NumericVector> t=R_NilValue,
                          Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::NumericVector> tmax=R_NilValue,
                          Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::NumericVector> tmin=R_NilValue){
      int N=0;
      if(t.isNotNull()) {
        N=t.size(); /* which show a error*/
      }else{
        N=tmax.size(); /* which show a error*/
      }
      NumericVector yout=NumericVector(N);

      if(t.isNotNull()) {
        for(i=0;i<N,i++){
          yout[i]=2*t[i]
        }
      }else{
        for(i=0;i<N,i++){
          yout[i]=(tmax[i]-tmin[i])*(tmin[i]+tmax[i])
        }
      }
      return(yout)
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling, e.g. `.size()` directly on the object as you are doing here -- `N = t.size();` -- you need to cast it to the underlying type. For example,

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int nullable_size(Nullable<NumericVector> x_ = R_NilValue)
{
    if (x_.isNotNull()) {
        NumericVector x(x_.get());
        return x.size();
    }
    warning("argument x_ is NULL");
    return -1;
}

/*** R

nullable_size(rnorm(5))
# [1] 5

nullable_size(NULL)
# [1] -1
# Warning message:
# In .Primitive(".Call")(<pointer: 0x000000006aa417a0>, x_) :
#   argument x_ is NULL

*/
```

As pointed out by Dirk, the use of `.get()` is not strictly necessary here --  using `NumericVector x(x_);` will invoke [`Nullable<>::operator SEXP()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/Nullable.h#L79-L82) and work equally well.

---

Also, please format your code better in the future.

Comment: Correct answer, and very correct hint about formats.  This simply lacked the _instantiation_ of the variable you want the size of.  I actually prefer [this simpler form](https://github.com/aliceyiwang/mvabund/blob/master/src/Rinterface.cpp#L52-L53). It works the same way with `NumericVector` and other `SEXP`-compatible types.